# How to get a model in controller laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new in laravel and i'm trying to get model post from view in controller method. I used **Collective\Html\FormFacade** for a view. My view code is below;

```
{!! Form::model($employee,array("url" => "employee/edit" , "method"=>"POST")) !!}
    <ul>
        <li>
          {{ Form::label('Name', 'Name') }}
        </li>
        <li>
          {{ Form::text('Name') }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            {{ Form::label('Job', 'Job') }}
        </li>
        <li>
            {{ Form::text('Job') }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            {{ Form::label('Salary', 'Salary') }}
        </li>
        <li>
            {{ Form::text('Salary') }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    {{ Form::submit('Update Employee!') }}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

My question is how can i get this post data as model in controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to instantiate a new model with it.

```
$employee = new Employee($request->all())
```

If you are updating the record then retrieve it from the database using the id

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    $employee = Employee::find($id);
    $employee->fill($request->all());
    $employee->save();
    // ...
}
```

I suggest reading https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#basic-updates